# Host linux distro without GUI?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, terminal, vnc

I saw this video on Youtube: [Run Kali Linux on Android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uZ2eDb9EjzE)

The phone uses the app: Linux deploy, which uses the phone
to host the distro, but there's is no GUI. The only way to
connect to Kali, is by using a vnc viewer.

My question is:
Is it possible to host a linux distro on e.g. an laptop or
stationary, without GUI - only vnc? So that you need another
PC with a VNC Client to use the desktop itself.

Comment: If you're interested in saving resources on the system, X11 forwarding in lieu of VNC is a good mention as well. Linux clients should do it natively, but there's a program called [XMing](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) that enables Windows to do it as well. You'd still have to install all the GUI stuff (you could possibly get out of installing some xorg-specific stuff) but you get out of running a full DE if all you're interested in is a single application.

Comment: X11 forwarding in lieu of VN, is that not ssh? You are right, I want to save computer ressources, by not displaying the graphical interface on the host, but i still want to access the desktop graphically through VNC or something else :D

Comment: Alright, I was just putting it out there as a possible alternative. If you're actually wanting a full desktop, then VNC is probably the way to go with it since at that point you're basically running everything involved anyways. X11 forward is more for if you just wanted a single application.

Comment: What do you mean by single application, will the computer only run an single application? And will I be able to get the graphical interface for the application, if I choose this way?

Comment: For example, if you run `firefox` through X11 forwarding, it will run the browser on the OS you're connected to but the graphical display will be on your client. Works the same with any application (for example, graphical configuration tools). But if you're wanting a full DE anyways, then you would be essentially starting everything up anyways. So X11 won't gain you much if you do that. Unless you're alright with launch each graphical tool as you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is easy. Install the system with the GUI libraries for X (drivers optional) and for the desktop environment you want. Then, run something like the TigerVNC server, and you're done.

Comment: Will the linux distro run on the host without GUI then?

Comment: @ArneJensen Yes, if you configure it this way. How to do that specifically depends on the distro. In Fedora, you would run `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target` (as opposed to `graphical.target`).